# Are there any side-effects if you move your Documents to a network drive?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking

Simply said: I want to move all my Documents to a Network Share, which is provided by my router. I want to do this, because the Google Drive App fails to sync my Documents correctly.

It is actually possible to move windows standard folders, but are there are any side effects to move them to a network share? The special case about my network share is also, that is activated 30 seconds after a user logged in via script:

```
net use Z: \\readyshare\stick\nonofyourbusiness passwd /USER:admin /PERSISTENT:NO 
net use Y: \\readyshare\stick\Source passwd /USER:admin /PERSISTENT:NO 
net use X: \\readyshare\stick\Media passwd /USER:admin /PERSISTENT:NO
```

The 30 second delay is done via a task, because the network connection needs a few seconds for DHCP and all that.

So I would add another folder, which is called "Documents" and add it as W.

Are there any reasonable objections against this? How does Windows react to the delay of the shares?

Comment: You are talking about the users `Documents` folder (what we used to call "My Documents") .. correct? If so, you just need to make sure you have access to the network shares when using the Windows machine, since it doesn't do "roaming" profiles in that manner ..

Comment: @txtechhelp I thought I described the situation fairly well. I log on, the desktop appears and 30 seconds later the shares are connected. I can change the trigger for that script, but that is what I am asking. What do I need to do in Order for Windows to always accept the "My Documents" folder in a network share.

Comment: Have you tried moving them to that share? There's tons of tutorials and help sites for "moving My Documents" to other folders (i.e. right click on the folder you want to move->properties->location->move) .. if so, you need to make sure you always have access to those network shares .. otherwise windows will complain when it can't find it ..

Comment: @txtechhelp I know HOW to move it, my question is what will happen if windows launches and the network share is not ready yet. Because Windows does not remember network passwords, you need to reenter it, hence the script I wrote that automates that. So the question is, at what point does windows actually look for it and what happens if it is not available. Do I need to move it again? Can I automate it?

Comment: `Windows does not remember network passwords` .. it does if you tell it to .. `Connect using different credentials` and `Reconnect at logon` do this .. and if Windows can't find the path where your users folders are at (like Desktop) it will complain and just not load the profile, or not load the profile correctly (no start bar/background) and tell you to "try again later when the location becomes available" .. can't really `move it again` since you can't access the folder/profile .. Since it's on your router, something to think about if you use the computer outside of your network ..

Comment: You could look into roaming profiles, but that still duplicates the files/folders across devices (netshare to computer and vice versa), so not sure what you're trying to achieve other than to move the user documents folder to a network share accessible by anyone who can view it .. Also, if your concerned about a startup script happening before the user profile is loaded, take a look at the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit` .. that's the key/command that's called before the user files are loaded

Comment: @txtechhelp It is unfortunately a common problem that Windows 7 forgets the network credentials for shares and is unable to automatically log in. That is why I have scripts for it. Wouldn't use them if it would work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be an answer to your question but I think it may be a solution to your problem. It seems the real problem you're having is making sure you have a backup of your MyDocs. Rather than going to the unecessary effort of implementing folder redirection why don't you just find a working solution for your backup system. Windows may very well let you have such a long delay on startup but you may introduce problems because of the delay.

The simpler solution would be to use a different backup method. Robocopy is already on your system, you just need to configure it, type: robocopy /?  into the command prompt window and you'll see a help menu that you can go off. There's plenty of online guides for it also. It's a very powerful tool so be careful with your syntax and switch selection. Anyway, Just a suggestion. I know how much of a pain Drive can be, I ended up moving to Dropbox and it's been smooth sailing since then. Good luck.